# Cannot start any docker image: "Error response from daemon: containerd: container did not start before the specified timeout"

Tags: docker

I get an error "Error response from daemon: containerd: container did not start before the specified timeout" when starting any container with "docker run" or "docker start" commands.

Everything worked perfectly before, but today I cannot start any container. I tried to start 
hello-world image to check if there is some problem in container, but even hello-world doesn't start.

I stopped the docker daemon, reinstalled docker, and started docker daemon again, but nothing happened.

"journalctl -u docker.service" output:

`Dec 12 09:17:42 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:17:42.672563850+00:00" level=debug msg="Calling GET /_ping"
Dec 12 09:17:42 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:17:42.673293012+00:00" level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.32/containers/hello-world/json"
Dec 12 09:17:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:17:54.060871113+00:00" level=debug msg="Calling GET /_ping"
Dec 12 09:17:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:17:54.061191172+00:00" level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.32/containers/4cdeae309cb7/json"
Dec 12 09:17:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:17:54.062410203+00:00" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.32/containers/4cdeae309cb7c281775fe4d81a784fa66abb996141778a991940229451d2259f/attach?stderr=1&stdout=1&stream=1"
Dec 12 09:17:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:17:54.062511731+00:00" level=debug msg="attach: stderr: begin"
Dec 12 09:17:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:17:54.062520941+00:00" level=debug msg="attach: stdout: begin"
Dec 12 09:17:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:17:54.062727033+00:00" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.32/containers/4cdeae309cb7c281775fe4d81a784fa66abb996141778a991940229451d2259f/wait?condition=next-exit"
Dec 12 09:17:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:17:54.063544148+00:00" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.32/containers/4cdeae309cb7c281775fe4d81a784fa66abb996141778a991940229451d2259f/start"
Dec 12 09:17:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:17:54.066070847+00:00" level=debug msg="container mounted via layerStore: /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/efa1e6efad2fd48a90bb5c05926a0eedead9cea47bb9d817009262fe691ecbac"
Dec 12 09:17:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:17:54.066279692+00:00" level=debug msg="Assigning addresses for endpoint heuristic_ptolemy's interface on network bridge"
Dec 12 09:17:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:17:54.066294675+00:00" level=debug msg="RequestAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, , map[])"
Dec 12 09:17:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:17:54.116408690+00:00" level=debug msg="Assigning addresses for endpoint heuristic_ptolemy's interface on network bridge"
Dec 12 09:17:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:17:54.433426030+00:00" level=debug msg="Programming external connectivity on endpoint heuristic_ptolemy (5fed14fb7b8aa9dd2e63fe557095c9537b97d60a6399378bd7fe30ce15e37ab1)"
Dec 12 09:17:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:17:54.500290350+00:00" level=debug msg="EnableService 4cdeae309cb7c281775fe4d81a784fa66abb996141778a991940229451d2259f START"
Dec 12 09:17:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:17:54.500349668+00:00" level=debug msg="EnableService 4cdeae309cb7c281775fe4d81a784fa66abb996141778a991940229451d2259f DONE"
Dec 12 09:19:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:19:54.559513309+00:00" level=error msg="containerd: start container" error="containerd: container did not start before the specified timeout" id=4cdeae309cb7c281775fe4d81a784fa66abb996141778a991940229451d2259f
Dec 12 09:19:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:19:54.632021162+00:00" level=debug msg="attach: stdout: end"
Dec 12 09:19:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:19:54.632084134+00:00" level=debug msg="attach: stderr: end"
Dec 12 09:19:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:19:54.632474479+00:00" level=debug msg="Revoking external connectivity on endpoint heuristic_ptolemy (5fed14fb7b8aa9dd2e63fe557095c9537b97d60a6399378bd7fe30ce15e37ab1)"
Dec 12 09:19:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:19:54.636394649+00:00" level=debug msg="DeleteConntrackEntries purged ipv4:0, ipv6:0"
Dec 12 09:19:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:19:54.969487726+00:00" level=debug msg="Releasing addresses for endpoint heuristic_ptolemy's interface on network bridge"
Dec 12 09:19:54 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:19:54.969552532+00:00" level=debug msg="ReleaseAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, 172.17.0.2)"
Dec 12 09:19:55 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:19:55.102263367+00:00" level=debug msg="Failed to unmount efa1e6efad2fd48a90bb5c05926a0eedead9cea47bb9d817009262fe691ecbac aufs: device or resource busy"
Dec 12 09:19:55 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:19:55.102342789+00:00" level=error msg="Error unmounting container 4cdeae309cb7c281775fe4d81a784fa66abb996141778a991940229451d2259f: device or resource busy"
Dec 12 09:19:55 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:19:55.102381789+00:00" level=debug msg="GetMountID id: 4cdeae309cb7c281775fe4d81a784fa66abb996141778a991940229451d2259f -> mountID: efa1e6efad2fd48a90bb5c05926a0eedead9cea47bb9d817009262fe691ecbac"
Dec 12 09:19:55 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:19:55.102403179+00:00" level=debug msg="Cleaning up old mountid efa1e6efad2fd48a90bb5c05926a0eedead9cea47bb9d817009262fe691ecbac: start."
Dec 12 09:19:55 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:19:55.118602904+00:00" level=debug msg="Cleaning up old mountid efa1e6efad2fd48a90bb5c05926a0eedead9cea47bb9d817009262fe691ecbac: done."
Dec 12 09:19:55 ubuntu-server dockerd[20211]: time="2017-12-12T09:19:55.118734908+00:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.32/containers/4cdeae309cb7c281775fe4d81a784fa66abb996141778a991940229451d2259f/start returned error: containerd: container did not start before the splines 1361-1428/1428 (END)`

"docker version" output:

`Client:
 Version:      17.09.1-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   19e2cf6
 Built:        Thu Dec  7 22:24:23 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Server:
 Version:      17.09.1-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   19e2cf6
 Built:        Thu Dec  7 22:23:00 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false`

"docker info" output:

`Containers: 18
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 18
Images: 3
Server Version: 17.09.1-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 60
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 06b9cb35161009dcb7123345749fef02f7cea8e0
runc version: 3f2f8b84a77f73d38244dd690525642a72156c64
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-87-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.693GiB
Name: ubuntu-server
ID: LEXP:H2LQ:7JR3:6D2T:ZBCK:HFM6:Y3XP:RCT2:YWCP:JQRF:NSOW:TWVJ
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 17
 Goroutines: 25
 System Time: 2017-12-12T09:30:32.826784091+00:00
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
WARNING: No swap limit support`

I don't even know where to look, I cannot find any other logs.

Comment: Did you use a remote file system to mount a volume into any of the containers?

Comment: No. The problem disappeared after system restart. However, I still don't know the reason and how to fix it without restarting the system.